# Coding a Javascript HTML5 Scroll "Camera"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, view, scroll

I am a rookie html5/javascript/php/mysql programmer that just started out and needs some help.

I am trying to do something like this site http://space.angrybirds.com/launch/ where when you scroll down, instead of scrolling down the content like on a typical site, the "camera" kind of moves in another direction, to look at other content.

To give you a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish, here is a diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPY16.jpg (i cannot post images as this is my first post)

What I am trying to accomplish is not as complicated as the reference angry birds site, but rather just scrolling down but instead of scrolling down, it moves in a zig zag manner to the right.

Do you know what javascript libraries the angry birds site devs might have used to make the site? Any code snippets, library names, jQuery examples, would be very helpful to me!

Pardon me if I said any terms wrongly, and please do correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe looking for a Parallax Scrolling plugin

http://medleyweb.com/web-dev/15-useful-jquery-parallax-plugins-and-tutorials/